# Powershell if-else

Tags: powershell, if-statement

I want to write a powershell code like when you type Laskopia | LevTest | Drift | Pretest, then it will check that it is the correct and return it is correct and if it is not correct return that it is wrong

```
$Miljö = Read-Host "Enter Laskopia | LevTest | Drift | Pretest"

If ($Miljö -eq "Laskopia") { $Miljö = "Laskopia" }
If ($Miljö -eq "Levtest") { $Miljö = "Levtest" }
If ($Miljö -eq "Drift") { $Miljö = "Drift" }
If ($Miljö -eq "Pretest") { $Miljö = "Pretest" }
Write-Host "Miljön is $Miljö" -ForegroundColor Green 

else
Write-Host "Miljön finns inte" -ForegroundColor Red
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid repeating things, it's better to keep those valid values in an array and use such script:

```
$ValidValues = @("Some value", "Another", "Another one")
$Value = Read-Host "Enter one of following values: $($ValidValues -join " | ")"
if($ValidValues -icontains $Value){
    Write-Host "Value = $Value" -ForegroundColor Green
} else {
    Write-Host "$Value is not a value value." -ForegroundColor Red
}
```

Comment: I am Iranian and living in Sweden! I start with the powershell recently!

Comment: How can we write a loop? We want to be able to write again if we write the wrong value in Read-host!

Comment: `do { $Value = Read-Host "Enter one of following values: $($ValidValues -join " | ")"} while($ValidValues -inotcontains $Value)`

Comment: that not work `$ValidValues = @("Drift", "levtest", "Laskopia", "Pretest")
$Miljö = Read-Host "Enter Miljön: $($ValidValues -join " | ") "
if($ValidValues -icontains $Miljö)
{
    Write-Host "Miljö = $Miljö" -ForegroundColor Green
}
else
{
   Write-Host "$Miljö finns inte." -ForegroundColor Red
do { $Miljö = Read-Host "Enter Miljö: $($ValidValues -join " | ")"} while($ValidValues -inotcontains $Value)
} `

Comment: You just need to correct the while part: `while($ValidValues -inotcontains $Miljö)` You forget to rename `$Value` to `$Miljö`

Comment: can you check it out? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48191633/copy-subfolder-with-especially-name-powershell?noredirect=1#comment83364313_48191633

Comment: Not right now, but I'll take a look at it later and If I had any idea about that, I'll inform you :)

Answer (score 4):

You could also use a switch statement for that:

```
$Miljö = Read-Host "Enter Laskopia | LevTest | Drift | Pretest"
switch ($Miljö) 
{ 
    {$_ -in "Laskopia", "Levtest", "Drift", "Pretest"} { Write-Host "Miljön is $Miljö" -ForegroundColor Green }
    default { Write-Host "Miljön finns inte" -ForegroundColor Red }
}
```

You need Powershell 3.0 for the `-in` Operator

Comment: Even without using -in I would say switch is the best option.

Comment: @EBGreen switch is really lovely. But a switch with 2 statement, one for true one for false is never better than if/else. In fact, I believe it's is an example of when you should not use switch ;)

Comment: I certainly would not argue with that sentiment.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to argue it after all. At least based on speed, switch seems to perform faster than if-else.

Answer (score 3):

```
if ($Miljö -in ('Laskopia','LevTest','Drift','Pretest')) {
    Write-Host "Miljön is $Miljö" -ForegroundColor Green 
}
else {
    Write-Host "Miljön finns inte" -ForegroundColor Red
}
```

To force correct user input from a fixed selection, it's usually better to do something like:

```
do {
    $Miljö = Read-Host "Enter Laskopia | LevTest | Drift | Pretest"
while ($Miljö -notin ('Laskopia','LevTest','Drift','Pretest'));
```

Comment: If you type the wrong value then how can you write again?! instead of jumping out with the exit                                                                                           else {
    Write-Host "Miljön finns inte" -ForegroundColor Red exit

Answer (score 1):

An alternative method to the other answers is using a validation attribute:

```
[ValidateSet('Laskopia','LevTest','Drift','Pretest','Default')]
[String]$Miljö = 'Default'

Try
{
    $Miljö = Read-Host 'Enter Laskopia | LevTest | Drift | Pretest'
    Write-Host "Miljön is $Miljö" -ForegroundColor 'Green'
}
Catch
{
    Write-Host 'Miljön finns inte' -ForegroundColor 'Red'
}
```