# copy subfolder with especially name powershell

Tags: powershell, copy-item

How can I copy any subfolder with different names under a folder from a server and paste into my computer as a .zip fill ?!
I want to copy moon folders that are listed below $RootSourcePath\$Miljö\$År\$Månad\dag!

```
             $RootSourcePath = "D:\LogBackup\"
             $Miljö = Read-Host "Skriva in Miljö Namn under $RootSourcePath"


            If (test-path $RootSourcePath\$Miljö) {Write-Host "Miljön finns under LogBackup." -ForegroundColor Green}

  Else {
  Write-Host "Miljön finns INTE i LogBackup." -ForegroundColor Red

exit    
    }



   $År = Read-Host "Skriva in År under $RootSourcePath$Miljö" 
  If (test-path $RootSourcePath\$Miljö\$År) {Write-Host "År finns i         D:\LogBackup\$Miljö." -ForegroundColor Green}

  Else {
  Write-Host "År finns INTE i D:\LogBackup\$Miljö\$År." -ForegroundColor Red

exit
    }



     $Månad = Read-Host "Skriva in Månad under $RootSourcePath$Miljö\$År" 
   If (test-path $RootSourcePath\$Miljö\$År) {Write-Host "Månad finns i        $RootSourcePath$Miljö\$År." -ForegroundColor Green}

Else {
           Write-Host "Månad finns INTE i $RootSourcePath\$Miljö\$År." -ForegroundColor Red

exit
}



          $Dag = Read-Host "Skriva in Dag under $RootSourcePath$Miljö\$År\$Månad" 
         If (test-path $RootSourcePath\$Miljö\$År\$Månad) {Write-Host "Dag finns i $RootSourcePath$Miljö\$År\$Månad." -ForegroundColor Green}

       Else {
               Write-Host "Dag finns INTE i $RootSourcePath\$Miljö\$År\Månad." -ForegroundColor Red
        exit

      }
```

Comment: What version of PowerShell are you using, and on what version of Windows?

Comment: Are you asking how to zip every $Månad and save it from the server to your computer?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin   Powershell version 4.0, windows server 2012 r2! I can ignore creating zip file because it does not work with powershell 4.0 I guess!
but how can I copy 10 subfolders of 20 subfolders!
for example we have
foldder-AP-1
folder-AP 2
folder-AP-3
...
folder-ap-20

but we should copy only folder-ap-4 to folder-ap-12!

Comment: @notjustme How can I copy any subfolder under less than $ day! For example, we have catalog-ap-1 to directory-ap-20 for $ day
but I just want to copy directory-ap-5 to directory-ap-15 and create a folder with a special name on server!

Comment: `Compress-Archive : The term 'Compress-Archive' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelli
ng of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Admin\JBoss-scripts\GenerellaScript\IX3Leverans kopiering\ix3logg.ps1:48 char:1
+ Compress-Archive -Path $RootSourcePath\$Miljö\$År\$Månad\$Dag -Destination C:\Ad ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Compress-Archive:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException`